# How to find Expected Value of Absolute value of X

Tags: probability, statistics

[Problem Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpwKk.png)

Let Y = |X| Calculate E[Y].

How can I find the E[Y].

I am a complete newbie in statistics. Please help me out. Thanks!!

Comment: Also newbies are able to take knowledge of their lecture notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. The distribution of $Y$ is given by $P(Y = 0) = 1/9$ and $$P(Y = 1) = P(Y = 2) = P(Y = 3) = P(Y = 4) = 2/9.$$

Do you know how to calculate $E(Y)$ from this?

Answer (score 0):

You can first go hunting for the distribution of $Y$ and then apply the definition of $\mathbb EY$ (see the answer of aduh for this).

Alternatively you can make use of the definition of $\mathbb Ef(X)$ where $f$ denotes some measurable function.

It is beyond doubt that these definitions can be found in your textbook.